# How to run a function on Power button 3 times click?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am setting up a SOS app, I want to set up a alert function on Power button 3 times press. If a user press power button 3 times then function will triggered. It will also work when phone is locked.
How to do that on Expo(React Native)

Answer (score 0):

currently there are no Hardware keys API (Volume UP/DOWN, power button) available in Expo